# I am trying to search the student result using registration# ? Help appricated

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

need help to search the data, when I enter the registration number it is not giving me the details which I have typed in the admin page. need help ??? home.html I don't know how to place data for display and also in other stuff.

---

### moodle.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.encoding import smart_text

class ResultQuery(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=150)
    dept_name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    cgpa=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    reg_number=models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
       return smart_text(self.name)
```

---

### app==> url.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home),
]
```

---

### forms.py

```
from django import forms

class ResultForm(forms.Form):

      Reg_No  =forms.CharField(label="Registration Number")
```

---

### views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import ResultForm
from .models import ResultQuery



def home(request):
    form=ResultForm(request.POST or None)
    template_name = "home.html"
    context = {"form": form}
    if form.is_valid():
        objects = ResultQuery.objects.filter(reg_number=form.cleaned_data['Reg_No'])
        context['objects'] = objects

    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

---

### admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import ResultQuery

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(ResultQuery),
```

---

### home.html

```
<h1>Search Your Result</h1>

<form method="POST" action=" "> {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Note: I would like to do the search and display the data, help me in HTML page also.
screenshots for reference.

Comment: See the link for the search function https://stackoverflow.com/q/65592686/8519353

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set `context['objects'] = objects`. This means you can use this in your template to get the `ResultQuery` objects:

**home.html**

```
<h1>Search Your Result</h1>

<form method="POST" action=" "> {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>

{% for result_query in objects %}
    {{ result_query.name }}
    {{ result_query.dept_name }}
    {{ result_query.cgpa }}
    {{ result_query. }}
{% endfor %}
```